# How to get list of PID for all the running process with python code?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a project which needs the list of PID of all the running process. I want it via python programming language. How to get it? Thanks in adv.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar, Yes it solves partially my problem but this solution seems specific to windows OS. I want generic solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are on Linux just use `subprocess.Popen` to spawn the `ps - ef` command, and then fetch the second column from it. Below is the example.

```
import subprocess as sb

proc_list = sb.Popen("ps -ef | awk '{print $2} ' ", stdout=sb.PIPE).communicate()[0].splitlines()

for pid in proc_list:
    print(pid)
```

If you want to keep it platform independent use `psutil.pids()` and then iterate over the pids. You can read more about it [here](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#processes), it has bunch of examples which demonstrates what you are probably trying to achieve.

Hope this helps.

Please execuse any typo if any, i am just posting this from mobile device.

If you want a dictionary with pid and process name, you could use the following code:

```
import psutil

dict_pids = {
    p.info["pid"]: p.info["name"]
    for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=["pid", "name"])
}
```

Comment: Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it helped you.